# What is the word for thinking about what someone is thinking?

Tags: single-word-requests

In chess, you constantly think what your opponent might be thinking. Is there a specific word in English for this?

*Meta-cognition* comes close, but not exactly what I am looking for. *Guessing, predicting*, and *psychoanalysis* are obviously not what I am looking for.

---

**Edit**: I am looking for a single word (not a phrase) that is closest to this.

Comment: @Shyam Actually I am searching for one word, mind-reading is a sort of a phrase

Comment: added the tag to clearly specify that you are looking for a single word and not a phrase.

Comment: Why do you expect a single word? Is this at the tip of your tongue but you can't remember it?  Or do you have a single word for it in your first language (if not English)?

Comment: @Mitch In so vast English language I think such word does exist. There are a lot of instances where I would like to use such word. Why use a phrase or a sentence to explain something when you can use a word for it .

Comment: meta-cognition, theory of mind, mind-games (though that is more emotional), it doesn't seem there is a good single word for it, except meta-cognition, but it's somehow not satisfying.

Comment: Quaila or mind theory if I remember correctly is that you have an 85% chance of been correct about someone’s thoughts that’s very close to you, if you think you know someone slow down takes years to be close to knowing someone. No one knows what makes us us and exactly where consciousness exists in our brain it’s like asking how bigs the universe, we can do so much as humans but can’t simply create a blade of grass, why we are here no one knows but something can’t come from nothing. Iv never let off a fire work and a little plant was left over the Big Bang is ridiculous because if it’s so big

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think we can use **[foresee](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/foresee).**   **Anticipate** is also a good word.

Answer (score 4):

Is *outwit* any closer to what you are looking for?

Other suggestions: *outsmart* or *anticipate* (so that you anticipate what other player is thinking).

Just my two cents.

Answer (score 3):

In chess you are constantly ***second-guessing*** your opponent.

ODO:

> **[second-guess](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/second-guess)**
>
> *VERB*
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>
> **1** Anticipate or predict (someone's actions or thoughts) by guesswork.
>
> ‘We've been trying to second-guess Augusta all week but there's no
>   sense in trying any longer.’

Answer (score 2):

*Contemplate* could be very close to the word you are searching. It means “thoughtful observation or study” as mentioned in various dictionaries.

*Conjecture* and *anticipate*  are pretty close too.

Answer (score 1):

You could use **[discerning](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/discern?s=t)**:

"I am attempting to discern what my opponent will do next"

Or **[calculating](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/calculate?s=t)**:

"I am calculating his next moves"

Comment: @KitFox thanks for editing in the links, much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

**Telepathize:** *(v.)* to practice telepathy
**Clairavoyance**, **Mind-reading** and **Empathize** also have similar meaning.

Comment: Telepathize means to communicate through minds. It wasn't what I was searching for.

Answer (score 0):

As a chess player, I think of it with the phrase putting myself in the other guy's shoes or mindset.

As an AI programmer, I think of it as *minimax* — the name of the algorithm which has you maximizing from your perspective and minimizing for the other person's turn (or turning the board around, and complementing the scores so you are maximizing from their perspective).

Apart from that the best words we've been able to come up with are words like empathy or perspicacity or insight or rapport.

The Orwellian coinage close to this is *doublethink*.

Another phrase is *perspective shift*.

Comment: +1 I think _empathy_ and _strategy_ are about the closest single word candidates. I like _doublethink_ too.

Comment: @coleopterist Doublethink is the act of sincerely holding directly contradictory opinions or beliefs simultaneously. It does not describe the act of thinking about someone else's thoughts in any way at all - it doesn't belong on this list. I hope you haven't been misusing it for the past decade.

Answer (score 0):

You could use *inversion*. It's a general term, but could be used effectively with context.

I think *reverse psychology* is the term people would normally reach for, but you're looking for a single word.

Comment: can you explain how you can use inversion in this context ? It means the act of inverting. So how can I use it in this context ?

Comment: It'd have to be something of a term, so other people would need to know what you meant by it, in a chess context, before you used it. Then, I'd say something like "Her strategy sucks, but she excels at inversion."

Comment: It's common to have these kinds of terms in sports, but they need to be established before you can use them. That's circular, but what normally happens is a longer term gets shortened as people become familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

In psychology a close concept is [mentalizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mentalization). Wikipedia's current definition, isn't bad:

> Mentalization can be seen as a form of imaginative mental activity
>   that lets us perceive and interpret human behaviour in terms of
>   intentional mental states (e.g., needs, desires, feelings, beliefs,
>   goals, purposes, and reasons).

Answer (score -1):

Was the word ‘sonder’?  I found this thread trying to look for the word sonder and thought it might also be the word you were looking for.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).